# How to kill a running python process?

Tags: python, linux, shell

How to kill a running python in shell script when we know the python file name `xxx.py`?
(it is executed by cmd `python xxx.py`)

I can use `ps aux | grep python` to get the pid of it. and then
`kill pid` to terminate it.

but every time, I have to execute two cmd. Is there a good way to do it?

Comment: Does that work? If not try kill -9 pid

Comment: With a mongoose :D (sorry) - what's the problem with your approach?

Comment: if it's running, then it's not a python, pythons don't have feet

Answer (score 63):

The `pkill` utility can look at command lines when sending signals:

```
pkill -f xxx.py
```

Comment: This isn't working... no errors are returned, but `ps aux | grep python` shows that the script is still running...

Comment: ^ Seconded, doesn't work for me